# How to remove child in ccTouchEnded if i defined outside init

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I am not able to remove child if i define outside of init function. I want to remove child which is defined outside the init method. I use the following code in ccTouchEnded function to remove child.

Creating a sprite in `ccTouchMoved function`.

```
 sprite2 = CCSprite::create("circle1.png");
 sprite2->setPosition(ccp(winwsize/3.2, winhsize/1.3));
 this->addChild(sprite2, 1);
```

Removing a child in `ccTouchEnded function`.

```
 this->removeChild(sprite2);
```

Comment: Can you post more codes? Hard to diagnose.

Comment: sprite2 = CCSprite::create("circle1.png");
 sprite2->setPosition(ccp(winwsize/3.2, winhsize/1.3));
 this->addChild(sprite2, 1);

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive, so `Sprite2` and `sprite2` are two different things.

Comment: By mistake i put Sprite2 instead of sprite2.

Comment: Still it is not working

Comment: `sprite2` is defined as global variable, right? (though you didn't show it). No error shown, right?

Comment: Yes, sprite2 is declared as global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the sprite in touchesMoved therefore the sprite is created every time the touch moves and it is placed on the previous sprite. Your variable sprite2 will simply point to the last created sprite. Therefore when you remove child in touchesEnded, only the last sprite gets removed. Try creating sprite in touchesBegan and removing in touchesEnded.